# How can I unlock my frp-locked Samsung Galaxy A5 8.0 Oreo without enabling Developer Options?

Tags: galaxy, frp

i need some help my neighbor has given me a Samsung Galaxy A5 8.0 Oreo
its frp locked so i cannot enable Developer Options ,  now someone told me that it could be done via wireless ,  but i dont know the steps ...im not entirely a Noob but stuff i know is cuz i read instructions as i do the steps ...so ya ima a Noob ...lol  plz help and tell me a way to unlock this phone whether it be flashing or whatever ..i need a work phone and im a cheap ass

ive tried to use odin to flash but didnt work it passed but nothing happened